# A non-VBA recursive factorial function?

Tags: excel, recursion, excel-formula

Is it possible to, by enabling circular references (select `enable iterative calculation` in the `Formulas` part of `Excel Options`), create a recursive factorial function in Excel? I know about `FACT()` of course and am not looking for a practical way to compute factorials. Rather, my goal is to find a way to exploit circular references as a general tool for creating and using recursive functions in Excel and factorials provide an interesting test case.

Using an idea from Jan Karel Pietrerse's [website](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/circularreferences03.asp) I am able to get close but the resulting function depends on two cells rather than just one, so it doesn't solve the problem. In

[image]

I created named ranges using the strings in the top row. In the cell now named `factorial` I entered:

```
=IF(initializing,1,IF(factor=0,factorial,factorial*factor))
```

and in cell `factor` I entered:

```
=IF(initializing,n,IF(factor=0,factor,factor-1))
```

The above image shows what things look like when `n = 10` and `initializing = True`. The formula in `factorial` corresponds to a standard trick in functional programming to make a recursive function [tail-call recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) by introducing a helper function with an accumulating parameter. The problem is that helper function needs to be called and the formula in factorial is in some sense both the function itself and its helper function, with the contents of `initializing` determining what role it is currently playing.

What I have works in the sense that if I switch the value of `initializing` away from True (e.g. just delete it) then the value of `factorial` becomes the correct factorial:

[image]

Can `initializing` be removed from the picture? Is it possible to modify the set-up so that if e.g. `n` is changed to 5 then `factorial` instantly changes to 120 without needing to first set and then change some other cell? I've tried a couple of different things but keep ending up with 2-step rather than 1-step functions. Maybe some wizardry involving array formulas?

Comment: I don't understand how this is working when you have the formula directly refer to itself. Is it not giving you a circular reference error? And what does it mean, conceptually, to say "= itself", anyway?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is a circular reference. In the first sentence of the question I mentioned enabling circular references. (I just added a brief parenthetical about how to do so).

Comment: Any particular reason why the built-in function FACT() isn't good enough?

Comment: You can easily do that in VBA, but I suspect that using Circular references for such purposes in your sheet will result into something unnecessarily complex AND a performance nightmare.

Comment: @rskar -- no reason whatsoever. I explained that I chose the factorial function simply as a test case. I could have chosen Fibonacci numbers or any of the other recursive functions that are often used as examples when studying recursion.

Comment: @iDevlop The goal is to be able to, if possible, harness Excel's ability to do iterative calculation. Excel's calculation engine is quicker than its VBA interpreter, so my ultimate goal is to find a way to shunt certain recursive computations from VBA to Excel. It might not be worth it, but it can't hurt to explore the possibilities.

Comment: If there's a performance issue you're concerned with, but you want to avoid manually pre-setting values to get the circular reference errors to be blocked, perhaps set a VBA macro that runs when the 'n' cell changes, which goes in and automatically sets up your presets in the other cells? This would allow you to get the iterative performance native to Excel (though I have no experience with this), while still making it automated.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon You are correct that VBA can toggle the contents of `initializing` with a `change` event handler to mimic a recursive function of one cell, but part of my goal here is to get a better mental model of the nature of the recursion that enabling iterative calculation provides. It's a weird sort of fixed-point iteration. Is there a trick to turn it into full-fledged recursion? There is some theoretical result I saw somewhere that fixed-point combinators suffice for general recursion, but I don't really understand combinatory logic so am unsure if it applies here.

Comment: @JohnColeman My understanding of Excel's iteration is that it literally just bruteforces calculations for the number of times you indicate (set in the options next to 'allow iterative calculations', as you most likely know). This may make it 'perform better' than using VBA's own recursion abilities (again, I have no idea on this), but it is not 'true' recursion, it is only iteration.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon That is the connection with tail-call recursion since it is that sort of recursion which can be most easily replaced with iteration behind the scenes. But even if you think of it as iteration, it is still an interesting question if you can use that iteration to write a purely non-VBA factorial function of just 1 variable. What sort of iteration does circular references enable you to do?

Comment: @JohnColeman I've used a similar approach to cycle through random variables finding matches in simple circumstances not requiring a VBA setup, but honestly I find it easier in most cases to do that with the DATA -> What-If Analysis functions. If it's too complex of a problem to find using that, I would generally reach for VBA before trying something else. I didn't realize you could do what you're doing here, to actually allow iterations manually like that; I've never gotten that to work, so thanks for the info on that, if nothing else. I'm not a math guy so I've never used it for 'recursion'.

Comment: By the way Excel's iterative calculation method is not very efficient ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a formula with only one helper cell, updating automatically whenever `n` is changed, of course the helper column is more complicated compared to your original one:
[image]

- helper: `=IF(C2<>TEXT(A2,"0"),IF(ISNUMBER(C2),IF(C2=A2,TEXT(A2,"0"),C2+1),1),C2)`
- factorial: `=IF(ISNUMBER(C2),IF(C2=1,1,C2*D2),D2)`

The key is to change the helper cell when the result is reached (could be also negated, completed with a text (e.g. `A1&" Finished"`, the important to make it clear it reached end of calculation and also keep it comparable with the input cell).

Just for fun, array formula without iteration in F2: `=PRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&A2,TRUE)))`

### Update

Formulas step by step:
helper:

- stable state is formatted as text, as far as value of text is the same as `n` nothing happens, formula doesn't change the value in `helper`
- once `n` is changed: first criteria `C2<>TEXT(A2,"0")` will be false, but `helper` is still text, so second criteria is also false, `helper` is reset to 1
- after that `helper` is incremented until it reach `n`, when target is reached `helper` is converted to text to mark that calculation is finished

factorial:

- while `helper` is text nothing happens
- once `helper` is number: if it's 1 then `factorial` is reset to 1, else multiplication `helper * factorial` is calculated

Comment: Very nice. I am going to need to think about it for a while before I completely understand what is happening with the `Text` and `IsNumber`, but it seems like the text "0" to number 0 transition roughly corresponds to deleting the value of `Initializing` in my original set-up, and since Excel does the type-casting automatically the computation doesn't require human intervention at that step. (The array formula is also nice, though not nearly as surprising).

Comment: @JohnColeman: I've added also step by step description to make it more clear.

Comment: Good explanation. The way you control calculation by switching back and forth between text and numbers is quite clever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to remove "initializing" variable from the algorithm.

Let's look for an example.

[image]

[image]

I got 3 cells called: `number`, `factorial`, and `iteration`.

First of all, main thing that you should remember while using iteration calculations is the `IF` statements checking for 0, because the empty cell is 0 by default, and, as we know, zeros in the multiplications (the main part of factorial) is bad idea.

The `iteration` cell got this formula:
`=IF(i=0, number+1,i-1)`

The `factorial` cell got this formula:
`=IF(factorial=0, 1, IF(i=1, factorial, factorial*i))`

So if in the `iteration` cell is 0 or 1 (it depends on excel choice, and moon phase also) in the `factorial` cell you should get the right answer.

Of course by changing the `number` you can notice that the `iteration` cell is not 0 or 1, and the `factorial` not looks like expected result. Try to press <kbd>F9</kbd> until you don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Say we wanted to create a factorial formula with the following restrictions:

1. Don't use the built-in `FACT()` worksheet function
2. Don't enable iterative calculation
3. Don't use VBA
4. Don't use manually entered array formulas
5. Don't use "helper" cells

Using **Excel 365**, in cell **A1** enter some value *(say 8)*
In **A2** enter:

```
=PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(A1))
```

[image]

The `SEQUENCE()` function gives a "history" of 8 and allows us to ?simulate? recursion.

**EDIT#1:**

Using **Excel 2007** on my Win 7 machine, this **array formula**:

```
=PRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & A1)))
```

[image]

Gives the equivalent.  I had to violate restriction #4 because there are no dynamic spill-downs in **Excel 2007**.

Comment: Interesting. `SEQUENCE` isn't available in Excel 2016. One of my motivations for asking the question was an idle curiosity if Excel without VBA was [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). Your solution seems more iterative than recursive, but it is enough to suggest that Excel's recent spreadsheet functions might be enough to make the spreadsheet formula language Turing complete, even without circular references enabled (but maybe with array formulas).

Comment: @JohnColeman  If I can boot up my old WIN 7 laptop, I will try to to find a equivalent on an older version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I meant by my comment - use VBA to "check/uncheck" the initializing box, whenever "n" is changed in value.

I tried this with the named ranges you have in your example, and it works for me. Can extrapolate to use for your other purposes; the key here is that you will still need an 'initializing' cell [really you could just have 'initializing' be a named range that solely refers to a boolean value, not a cell that contains a boolean value], but it will at least be automated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = Range("n").Address Then

    Range("initializing").Formula = True
    Range("initializing").Formula = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this since it is the sort of thing that *might* be needed if we are to use Excel's iterative calculation from VBA but I won't (yet) accept it as the final answer since I still want to know if it is possible to get the purely non-VBA version down to a single input cell.